# How to enable other users to test my unpublished Google Editor Add-On w/o sharing projects or spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I've created a Google Sheets add-on as a user-controlled Google Cloud Project. It is unpublished. I have added a few test users through the OAuth consent screen section of the Google Cloud Platform web interface:
[image: screenshot showing 2 test users]

How can I enable these users to see my add-on? Do I need to create a test deployment that is attached to a specific sheet of theirs, or is there a way for them to install the add-on without my [sharing the project source code with them](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on)? I do not have the option of publishing privately within a domain.

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I did not see any that involved sharing with test users added through the OAuth settings and that did not require sharing either the project or the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with a Google Docs add-on.  Did you ever figure out how to distribute the add-on to the test users?

Comment: @Andrew I'm afraid not.